# Can my kid fly with an expired passport domestically within USA?

Tags: usa, domestic-travel, expired

I have a valid state ID card, but my kid's passport expired and we are actually flying to a city where a consulate/embassy exists to collect his new passport.

#### Can my kid fly with an expired passport domestically within USA?

[AllGetaways.com](https://%20https://www.allgetaways.com/international-travel/can-kids-travel-domestically-expired-passport.html) says

> Children traveling domestically by air do not need to present a valid passport at the airport. The specific rules of travel vary slightly from airline to airline, and many require that if the child is traveling with an adult, the adult must provide documentation to prove his age. Before booking a domestic flight, check with the airline about its specific requirements for children so that you're prepared with the correct documents, if needed.

But I'm unsure if the information is trustworthy or relevant to US domestic travel.

Comment: Do you hold that expired passport? It may not be an legal ID, it should be enough to prove their age. If you do not have it, do you have other paperwork that you can use to show the age?

Comment: Why aren't you sure if it's relevant to US domestic travel if the first sentence says "domestically"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For TSA security checkpoint purposes, children under 18 do not need any type of ID. See the TSA [identification](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) page:

> Children
>
> TSA does not require children under 18 to provide identification when
> traveling within the United States. Contact the airline for questions
> regarding specific ID requirements for travelers under 18.

Whether the airline might have additional requirements is up to the airline. I have never needed to present ID for my young children traveling domestically in the US.

Comment: which begs the question: how does the TSA verify that someone is under 18 if they don't have any ID ?

Comment: They ask the minor their age (which they verify against the boarding pass) and a few other questions until they're satisfied.

Comment: Indeed, my son used to get a few questions from TSA before he got his drivers license.

Comment: Anyone (possibly just US citizens?) can actually travel domestically without any ID. TSA will pull you aside and make you answer some questions over the phone to confirm your identity on your boarding pass. I wouldn't want to rely on this method regularly but it worked for me one time when I lost my wallet.

Comment: @wearebob that applies to foreigners too, but since the data they check seems to come from credit bureaus I wonder whether they can handle someone who lives outside the US and has no US credit record.

Comment: @phoog: I imagine they just ask you questions for three hours, and then inform you that, unfortunately, you seem to have missed your flight.

Comment: Perhaps not relevant here,but as an adult Australian citizen I couldn't checkin for a domestic flight in Canada without my passport - no other form of government issued ID was acceptable.

Comment: @John3136 Canada, which is not a constituent state of the USA, has much stricter rules on pre-boarding identification requirements than the US, uniformly imposed by [Transport Canada](https://travel.gc.ca/air/identification-requirements). Only IDs issued by *Canadian* government (federal or provincial) are acceptable, other than prescribed foreign IDs accepted to enter Canada (passport, NEXUS cards, U.S. Green card etc.).

Comment: you'd think that the renewed focus on human trafficking (especially of children) would have caused stricter regulations for traveling with children...

Comment: @jwenting I think it's primarily based on the difficulty of getting identity documents for children, especially photo IDs, especially when kids grow and have their appearance change so (relatively) quickly.

Comment: @WBT other countries don't have that problem...

Comment: @jwenting many other countries also do not require ID for children.  EasyJet, for example, requires ID for children on domestic flights only in Italy.

Comment: @phoog the US have a renewed campaign focusing on human trafficking of children since a few years, most other countries don't... Italy also has a problem with that, because of mostly slave traders from north Africa abducting children there and transporting them to slave auctions in Africa and Arabia.